# How do I fix this overflow problem when using hover function

Tags: html, css

I have create this container including movie item list and I tried to use hover function. The problem is when I hovering an img the rest of information is hidden from another container list. How do I get this hovering item overflow another container list. Like for example when I hovering an img. It should display the img and information such as Squid game and icon below but it has been hidden from another container. Here is my code:

```css
.movie-list-container{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -16vh;
    height:64vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.movie-list-wrapper{
   /* position: relative; */
   display: flex;

}

.movie-list{
    /* position: relative; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.movie-list-title{
    font-size: 23px;
}

.movie-list-item{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    /* position: relative; */
    border-radius: 10px;
   
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-item-img {
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-left:58px;
    padding-right: 58px;
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    opacity: 1;
    /* position: relative; */
}

.movie-list-item:hover{
    background-color: black;
    padding: auto;
 
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-item-icon{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-title{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-desc{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-type{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-icon{
    padding-left: 37px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /* position: relative; */
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}

.movie-title{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    /* overflow:hidden; */
}

.movie-list-item-icon{
    padding-left: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.movie-list-item-img{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width: 235px;
    height: 136px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.movie-list-desc{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.movie-list-type{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<div class="movie-list-container">
        <h1 class="movie-list-title">Phim Mới Ra</h1>
        <div class="movie-list-wrapper">
            <div class="movie-list">
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>                                                
</div>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-right arrow"></i>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-list-container">
        <h1 class="movie-list-title">Phim Mới Ra</h1>
        <div class="movie-list-wrapper">
            <div class="movie-list">
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>                                                
</div>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-right arrow"></i>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning the text inside `.movie-list-item` isn't showing on `:hover`? Your text is there but it's black text on a black background. I changed the text to white to show that the text is still visible on the page. Of course it depends on what size screen you're viewing the page on, which is a different story (that would be a responsive question). When viewed full-size, the text is legible.

```css
.movie-list-container{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: -16vh;
    height:64vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.movie-list-wrapper{
   /* position: relative; */
   display: flex;

}

.movie-list{
    /* position: relative; */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.movie-list-title{
    font-size: 23px;
}

.movie-list-item{
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    /* position: relative; */
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
   
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-item-img {
    margin-top: -20px;
    padding-left:58px;
    padding-right: 58px;
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    opacity: 1;
    /* position: relative; */
}

.movie-list-item:hover{
    background-color: black;
    padding: auto;
 
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-item-icon{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-title{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-desc{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-list-item:hover .movie-list-type{
    opacity: 1;
}

.movie-icon{
    padding-left: 37px;
    margin-left: 37px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /* position: relative; */
    transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
}

.movie-title{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    /* overflow:hidden; */
}

.movie-list-item-icon{
    padding-left: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background: pink;

}

.movie-list-item-img{
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width: 235px;
    height: 136px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.movie-list-desc{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.movie-list-type{
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<div class="movie-list-container">
        <h1 class="movie-list-title">Phim Mới Ra</h1>
        <div class="movie-list-wrapper">
            <div class="movie-list">
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>                                                
</div>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-right arrow"></i>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-list-container">
        <h1 class="movie-list-title">Phim Mới Ra</h1>
        <div class="movie-list-wrapper">
            <div class="movie-list">
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>
                <div class="movie-list-item">
                    <img class="movie-list-item-img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-title">SQUID GAME</div>
                    <div class="movie-icon">
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i></i></span>
                        <span class="movie-list-item-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></i></i></span>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="movie-list-desc">
                        <p > 13+</p>
                    </div>
                        <div class="movie-list-type">
                            <p > Romantic . Action</p> 
                        </div>                                                
                </div>                                                
</div>
<i class="fas fa-chevron-right arrow"></i>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, I have tried to fix the heigh and color as the one above but I want to minimize the heigh between two containers as small as possible.

Comment: @MatchaLattee ok you need to reduce the margin-top for a lot of the text/icons in movie-list-item. I reduce it a little in the code snippet.